# Why libc enter address always change in redhat 7

Tags: redhat, libc, backtrace

I use `backtrace()` and `backtrace_symbols()` to get some information.
outputs looks like:

./a.out

```
....
    (_Z8fun+0x1d( [0x400bb3]
    /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (+0x7dc5) [**0x7f2cb2b99dc5**]
    /lib64/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d) [**0x7fc20a61cd**]
...
```

In redhat 7, the bolder addrs is always change between times,
while in redhat 6, the addrs looks fixed.

Comment: 0x7f2cb2b99dc5 and 0x7fc20a61cd is the float address

Comment: @BillalBEGUERADJ - Please try and do all the fixes when reviewing in the H&I queue. Don't forget  the titles and tags as well as the body text!

Comment: `setarch -R` (`setarch -R ./a.out`) may disable ASLR on single binary: https://linux.die.net/man/8/setarch `-R, "--addr-no-randomize"
Disables randomization of the virtual address space (turns on ADDR_NO_RANDOMIZE).`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In redhat 7, the bolder addrs is always change between times, while in redhat 6, the addrs looks fixed

The addresses change because most modern systems use [Address Space Layout Randomization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) to make certain class of exploits harder.

ASLR was introduced into the Linux kernel in 2001, and redhat-6.2 release predates this.

P.S. Using such an old distribution for anything is *ill*-advised: you are missing 16 years worth of security and performance improvements.

Comment: Is randomized address of shared library load address from kernel's ASLR or is it implemented inside `ld-linux`? There are http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/kernel/process.c?v=4.4#L499 `arch_align_stack` & `arch_randomize_brk` in kernel, first does respect `ADDR_NO_RANDOMIZE` from `setarch -R`. There is also  PF_RANDOMIZE flag in the current http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?v=4.4;i=PF_RANDOMIZE which probably will shift mmap with NULL address into random; but does ld-linux.so use NULL address as mmap argument for most libraries?

Comment: @osgx It is *impossible* for `ld-linux` to randomize load addresses, because the only way it could do that is with `mmap(..., MAP_FIXED, ...)`, but that would remove any pre-existing mapping, and the loader can't know whether such mappings exist. So yes: the kernel does it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and it has perfectly resolved my issue.